# iOS How To Keep Navigation Item Color From Changing When Global Tint Color Set?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, uiappearance, tintcolor

In iPhone and iOS 9.0, I am seeing something weird with the global tint color vs specific colors being set.

After setting the following code in the AppDelegate, the navigation item color changes after showing an alert.

```
    window!.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    // per docs "The tint color to apply to the navigation items and bar button items."
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

I want the navigation item color to keep the color I set. (Colors and screen shots are from a temp app I created to show the problem.)

Notice below how the "Home" Navigation Item changes to green which is the global tint color set in the App Delegate.

[image: Home Screen]

[image: First One]

[image: Second One]

[image: Alert Launched]

[image: First One With Changed Navigation Item Color]

Why did "Home" change to green? **How to keep it from doing that?**

Code is here: https://bitbucket.org/finneycanhelp/tintcolorwhat

Comment: Did you try set UINavigationBar's `tintColor` explicit without using appearance protocol? `myNavigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor]`?

Comment: That's a good question, psci. Due to the actual app (not this example app), consisting of many view controllers with navigation controllers, we need to use the appearance protocol.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if just setting the global tint color using the storyboard is the answer. I would want to be sure I *don't* set it programatically. I will check this option out in the real app. **We would greatly prefer a programatic approach** since we want a consistent look and feel across apps and thus that's why we're using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the global tint color using the storyboard and not programmatically seems like a viable solution.